# How is the Concept of masked convolutions in PixelRNN implemented?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-models

I am reading the PixelRNN paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06759). I am having a little trouble understanding how one implements the concept of masked convolutions. Section 3.4 states: 
"The masks can be easily implemented by zeroing out the corresponding weights in the input-to-state convolutions after each update."
What corresponding weights are being referred to here ? I understand that the purpose of this masking is to ensure that the conditioning is only on pixels which are to the top and left of the current pixel. However, how does one exactly ensure this masking ? A mathematical answer would be appreciated.

Comment: I was looking into this issue, and found [this post](http://sergeiturukin.com/2017/02/22/pixelcnn.html) very helpful. You can go straight to the section titled `Masks`.